# bootstrap3 pushing to 2nd row, or inside 1 long row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I've got a simple bootstrap layout, which looks like that at md-* size

```
1 - 2
3 - 4
5 - -
```

So basically at xs my layout looks like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

My target is to make my layout look like it is at md size, but change 2 and 4 columns at xs-* and sm-* sizes, so they look like that:

```
1
4
3
2
5
```

I've tried 2 rows or just one row, pushing and pulling - nothing helps.

Comment: Please provide a code preview.

Answer (score 0):

Without code preview it's kinda hard to say but you could try using

```
class="visible-xs-* visible-sm-*"
```

for the *1-4-3-2-5* mobile layout in combination with

```
class="hidden-md"
```

for your desktop layout.
Also try to experiment a little bit with hidden/visible in combination with xs/md - take a look here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

This gives you the possibility to make independent changes to the layout if you can't achieve what you're trying to do with responsive layout. But again: code preview please!

Answer (score 0):

For this exact layout, you'll need to use the utility classes for at least one of the columns which will require duplicate content. Here's an example that works duplicating the '3' column:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-md-push-12">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 visible-xs">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 hidden-xs">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-12">5</div>
  </div>
```

http://bootply.com/bLFQQ1aOhM